# DirectX calls not appearing

Tags: ida, functions, call

I'm trying to do some reverse-engineering to a DirectX 9 game. I've used PIX to see all the DirectX calls of the game, and that part worked correctly.

After that, I wanted to know where in the code those functions were called from. Therefore, I tried to use API Monitor, but there I got the first surprise: no calls were being found to **Graphics and Gaming/DirectX Graphics and Gaming** (where all the Direct3D functions are).

As that didn't work, I used IDA instead; In the Imports window, only these were being shown:
 [image]

And in the Functions window, none of the DirectX functions was found.

So, is this the proper way (if it's possible at all) of doing this? Also, how is that API Monitor doesn't register any DirectX calls, although PIX does?

Comment: Answered myself: only Direct3DCreate9 is imported, as the rest of API calls are from virtual tables.